# Converting circular structure to JSON ( where is the circulation happening? )

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, stringify

Getting the error `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON` on an object which doesn't have circular references.

I have tested the object in the console and had it stringified without a problem.
Even when I console log the object before passing it into the POST request, I get it stringified without a problem.

So I don't understand that on my Node server it throws this error when it gets to placing it into the request.

I have tried using npm packages `flatted` and `yarn add json-stringify-safe`, neither of which has helped.

Could it perhaps be caused by the request itself?

Here is the file contents:

```
const { inventorysource: { API_channel_ID, API_channel_ID_sandbox } } = require("../../config")

const post_order = async (instance, is_production, amount, user_data, res) => {
  const assemble_data = {
    order: {
      order_number: user_data.new_id,
      reference_number: user_data.new_id,
      ordered_at: String(new Date()),
      total_sale_price: amount,
      taxes: (amount / (100 + user_data.taxes)) * 100,
      notes: `${user_data.first_name} ${user_data.last_name}`,
      shipping: {
        method: user_data.shipping_info.name,
        address: {
          name: `${user_data.first_name} ${user_data.last_name}`,
          company: user_data.company,
          phone: user_data.phone,
          email: user_data.email,
          address: user_data.address_first,
          address2: user_data.address_second,
          city: user_data.city,
          state: user_data.state,
          zip: user_data.zip,
          country: user_data.country
        }
      },
      billing: {
        address: {
          name: `${user_data.billing_data.first_name} ${user_data.billing_data.last_name}`,
          company: user_data.billing_data.company,
          phone: user_data.billing_data.phone,
          email: user_data.billing_data.email,
          address: user_data.billing_data.address_first,
          address2: user_data.billing_data.address_second,
          city: user_data.billing_data.city,
          state: user_data.billing_data.state,
          zip: user_data.billing_data.zip,
          country: user_data.billing_data.country
        }
      },
      dealer: null,
      items: user_data.products_data
    }
  }

  const axios_instance = await instance

  const stringigied_data = JSON.stringify(assemble_data)

  try {
    const { data } = await axios_instance.post(
      `/channels/${ is_production ? API_channel_ID : API_channel_ID_sandbox }/orders`,
      stringigied_data
    )

    res.send({
      data: user_data,
      order_data: data,
      order_id: user_data.new_id
    })
  } catch(err) {
    res.send(err)
    console.log(err)
  }
}

module.exports = post_order
```

I have also tried commenting out the `items: user_data.products_data` to check if it might be causing it, but still the error persist.

I would expect the POST request to go through without a problem.

Comment: I suspect the circularity is in `user_data.products_data`. I assume all the other `user_data.XXX` properties that you use are strings.

Comment: Remove parts of the object until you no longer see the error and then reduce your problem to a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @shusson I will try it, the problem is that when I console.log it, I logs out JSON just fine without any issues. Thats whats strange about it.

Comment: @shusson Adding new comment under the code

Answer (score -1):

I think it trying to convert a JSON object that is already a JSON.

I will try to check from here up:

```
JSON.stringify(assemble_data)
```